# Python script - connect to SSH and run command

Tags: python, automation, ssh, telnet

I already know there are ssh modules for Python, that's not for what I'm looking for.
What I want to have is an python script to do the following:

1. > connect to an [ input by user ] SSH host
2. > connect using the credentials [ provided by the user ]
3. > run command on the SSH host [ telnet to [host - input by user ]
4. > Select menu item in the telnet session

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,

Comment: I don't get it. You need to do SSH-related stuff in Python and you are not interested in SSH modules for Python?

Comment: @Tokland, I'm looking for an example script. Not for answers like, "Fabric is a Python library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH" :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`paramiko`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/), see http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/ for a through example of using it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) or the [libssh2 python bindings](http://www.no-ack.org/2010/11/python-bindings-for-libssh2.html).

Answer (score 4):

now the popular solution is [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually looking for a module that lets you automate CLI interaction, there's [pexpect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries to do that.

1. Subprocess
2. Pexpect
3. Paramiko (Mostly used)
4. Fabric
5. Exscript

You can check their documentation for the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I will refer you to:

- [spur](https://pypi.org/project/spur/)

```py
import spur

shell = spur.SshShell(hostname="localhost", username="bob", password="password1", missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
result = shell.run(["echo", "-n", "hello"])
print(result.output) # prints hello
```

- [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko)

  - Login Through SSH Execute Command - [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHHYnQBm9V8)

```py
import paramiko

hostname = 'enter_host'
username = 'enter_user'
password = 'enter_pass'

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname, username=username, password=password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cd /enter/valid/path && ls -l')

for line in stdout:
    print(line.strip('\n'))

client.close()
```

output:

```sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 2712 Jan 22 14:49 file_1.ini
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 5928 Jan 22 14:50 file_2.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 1454 Jan 14 23:31 file_3.sql
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username  337 Jan 14 23:31 file_4.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 username username 4096 Jan 14 23:33 folder_1
drwxrwxr-x 2 username username 4096 Jan 14 23:33 folder_2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 2566 Jan 21 12:38 file_5.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username   63 Jan 14 23:31 file_6.txt
drwxrwxr-x 4 username username 4096 Jan 14 23:31 folder_3
drwxrwxr-x 9 username username 4096 Jan 21 12:38 folder_4
```

- No libraries required

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("ssh {user}@{host} {cmd}".format(user=user, host=host, cmd='ls -l'), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vassal](https://github.com/Shawn-Shan/vassal) package, which is exactly designed for this.

All you need is to install vassal and do

```
from vassal.terminal import Terminal
shell = Terminal(["ssh username@host", "cd scripts", "python foo1.py", "python foo2.py"])
shell.run()
```

This will run the command once every second, and you can make it run faster to change sec=0.1.